# Its possible to use a logback appender to send logs to kafka/rabbit-mq and then to Logstash (Elastic stack)?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, elk, spring-logback, distributed-tracing

## Context

- Microservices in the Cloud
- Components develop with Spring Boot, logback.xml
- We need Log Aggregation

Currently I can do it through TCP but I think this is not scalable enough in the AWS cloud, **can I send the logs using some Queue**?

> Microservice > appender logback.xml > Queue > Logstash > Elasticsearch

#### Appender

```xml
    <appender name="STASH"
              class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>localhost:5000</destination>

        <encoder
                class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <mdc/>
                <context/>
                <logLevel/>
                <loggerName/>

                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "serviceName": "clients-component",
                        "type": "business-capability"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>

                <threadName/>
                <message/>
                <logstashMarkers/>
                <stackTrace/>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

#### logstash.conf

```
input { tcp { port => 5000 codec => "json" } } 

output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"]} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Logstash to consume from message queues without any problem.

Currently Logstash has inputs for some message queues like [Kafka](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html), [RabbitMQ](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-rabbitmq.html) and [Redis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-redis.html).

Since you are using AWS, logstash also has input for [AWS SQS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-sqs.html).

You can check all logstash inputs in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html)